# Failing SSD, no bad sectors?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, nvme

Is it possible for an SSD to be failing but have no bad sectors reported?

Last night I accidentally filled up my SSD and started running into consistent errors on startup. I quickly freed up 40gb+ but am still running into issues

- Startup tries to recover journal, but freezes (subsequent restart usually doesn't need journal recover)
- After booting SSD begins failing between 1-30mins
- terminal shows Input/Output errors for non-builtin commands
- Plasma crashes
- Disconnect from net
- ctrl+alt+f2  stuck (no chance to login on this)

I booted into a live disc and SMART status and badblocks, but it looks like everything is good

SMART test

```
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo smartctl -H /dev/nvme0n1p3
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0n1
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0n1 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                    : 0
temperature                         : 49 C
available_spare                     : 100%
available_spare_threshold           : 10%
percentage_used                     : 0%
data_units_read                     : 6,371,635
data_units_written                  : 5,739,422
host_read_commands                  : 45,594,657
host_write_commands                 : 67,766,367
controller_busy_time                : 193
power_cycles                        : 124
power_on_hours                      : 478
unsafe_shutdowns                    : 20
media_errors                        : 0
num_err_log_entries                 : 1
Warning Temperature Time            : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time : 0
Temperature Sensor 1                : 49 C
Temperature Sensor 2                : 58 C
Temperature Sensor 3                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 4                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 5                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 6                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 7                : 0 C
Temperature Sensor 8                : 0 C

[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo nvme smart-log-add /dev/nvme0n1
NVMe Status:INVALID_LOG_PAGE(2109)


[liveuser@localhost nvmetest]$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1p3
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB
Serial Number:                      S59ANM0R108267E
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXM7
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size/Capacity:          1,000,204,886,016 [1.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            897,457,152,000 [897 GB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Local Time is:                      Thu Jun  3 14:32:39 2021 EDT
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL *Other*
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat *Other*
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.80W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     6.00W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.40W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0100W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02, NSID 0x1)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        62 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    0%
Data Units Read:                    10,303,901 [5.27 TB]
Data Units Written:                 5,869,634 [3.00 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 53,748,047
Host Write Commands:                75,706,248
Controller Busy Time:               278
Power Cycles:                       138
Power On Hours:                     508
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   28
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      2
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               62 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               81 Celsius

Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, max 64 entries)
No Errors Logged
```

badblocks

```
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/nvme0n1p3 > badsectors
Checking blocks 0 to 972042950
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)

[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo badblocks -v /dev/nvme0n1p2 > badsectors.swap
Checking blocks 0 to 4194303
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done                                                
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)

[liveuser@localhost ~]$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser    0 Jun  1 22:59 badsectors
-rw-rw-r--. 1 liveuser liveuser    0 Jun  1 23:38 badsectors.swap
```

fsck

```
[liveuser@localhost e2fsck]$ sudo ./e2fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p3: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p3: Clearing orphaned inode 10395651 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=040700, size=4096)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: Clearing orphaned inode 10377883 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600, size=4194304)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: Clearing orphaned inode 9963223 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100644, size=45036)
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 781268/60760064 files, 217936225/243010737 blocks
[liveuser@localhost e2fsck]$ sudo ./e2fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 781268/60760064 files, 217936225/243010737 blocks


[liveuser@localhost e2fsck]$ sudo ./e2fsck -f /dev/nvme0n1p3
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nvme0n1p3: 781268/60760064 files (1.0% non-contiguous), 217936225/243010737 blocks


[liveuser@localhost e2fsck]$ sudo ./e2fsck -c /dev/nvme0n1p3
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone                                                
/dev/nvme0n1p3: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/nvme0n1p3: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/nvme0n1p3: 781268/60760064 files (1.0% non-contiguous), 217936225/243010737 blocks


[liveuser@localhost e2fsck]$ sudo ./e2fsck -cvf /dev/nvme0n1p3
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errdone                                                
/dev/nvme0n1p3: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

/dev/nvme0n1p3: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

      781268 inodes used (1.29%, out of 60760064)
        6973 non-contiguous files (0.9%)
         470 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
             # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
             Extent depth histogram: 747824/2073
   217936225 blocks used (89.68%, out of 243010737)
           0 bad blocks
          21 large files

      684923 regular files
       58236 directories
           0 character device files
           0 block device files
           1 fifo
        1957 links
       38095 symbolic links (31358 fast symbolic links)
           4 sockets
------------
      783216 files
```

I've tried checking journalctl but it seems any errors aren't getting reported or flushed to disc in time before failing

```
[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo nvme list
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev 
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     S59ANM0R108267E      Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB             1         976.58  GB /   1.00  TB    512   B +  0 B   2B2QEXM7



[liveuser@localhost ~]$ sudo fstrim --verbose nvme
nvme: 95.5 GiB (102578487296 bytes) trimmed
```

Comment: Best way to test is to clone the SSD to a different disc and use that one instead.

Comment: Is that a copy&paste error in the first `fsck` block, where the third `fsck -p` run gives the same output as the first? This can happen legitimately when the SSD decides to go read-only so data can be salvaged, but if it's just pasted twice by accident, this would send us down the wrong path here.

Comment: @SimonRichter my apologies! That's a double paste, not a subsequent execution. Edited

Comment: Please run `smartctl -a` on the disk for full information. Running out of disk space can be pretty catastrophic for Windows.

Comment: Does `nvme list` show the namespace as fully in use? Are discards configured in the file system? Can you run `fstrim` on the file system while it is mounted?

Comment: (I mean, none of these should matter, really, SSDs need to be able to handle being full -- but having more than just the spare blocks to work with might help things along).

Comment: @SimonRichter Updated post w/ nvme list and fstrim. Still failing after login, but I guess that's expected :)

Comment: @harrymc forgive me, I'm not sure what the equivalent call is in nvme-cli , which I think I need to use for this? Also I'm running this on Linux in case that matters, but I'm guessing its just as catastrophic on there as it would be on Windows hah

Comment: You have been using smartctl, no? The command is perhaps `sudo smartctl -a /dev/nvme0n1p3`.

Comment: @harrymc oh man I'm such a dummy, yup its there and I edited the post w/  `smartctl -a`

Comment: I really wanted the SMART Attributes, so probably `smartctl -A`.

Comment: I believe my issue is related to https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195039  -- I've disabled APST and had stress tests running for 12 hours w/out fail. I'll let it run for another few days and follow-up w/ updates after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1 week of running w/out issue I believe my issue is related to an APST bug reported here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195039

I've disabled APST using the kernel startup arg below and now have no issues (but obviously need to find a better solution than disabling entirely)

```
nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0
```

---

I was able to get more information by booting into a live disc and mounting the drive, chrooting into the drive and running an IO stress test (I used Phoronix) until the drive started failing. Then I was able to escape the chroot and read dmesg to find a flood of errors similar to this

```
EXT4-fs error (device nvme0n1p3): ext4_find_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for an SSD to be failing but have no bad sectors reported?

Yes. Anomalies in error reports like SMART are correlated to higher drive failure rates, but not all failures are preceded by error reports.